# Add JFrame or JDialog to java netbeans application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, frame

I'm developing a java GUI application in netbeans 7,  I have a window that process files (SingleFrameApplication), and I need to launch a login screen before this main frame, 
I don't understand how to add the new frame, or how to delay the main frame until the login in the new frame is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved a similar problem was attaching a window listener to the main frame, that shows a modal confirm dialog.

Then if the dialog is confirmed but the login is wrong you can redisplay it. If it is canceled you can close the application.

```
   JPanel loginPanel = new LoginPanel();

   this.getFrame().addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void showLoginDialog()
        {
           int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                       mainView.getFrame(), 
                       loginPanel, "Login... ", 
                       JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
                       null);
          if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
          {
             if(!loginPanel.checkLogin())
             {
                 showLoginDialog();
             }
          }
          else
          {
             System.exit(0); // replace with your more graceful shutdown code
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) 
        {
           showLoginDialog();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to check it out